# Please unlock disk sda5_crypt

Tags: linux, ubuntu

cryptsetup: cryptsetup failed, bad password or options ?

Пароль забыт.

Есть возможности сбросить пароль ? или отключить шифрование диска ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: если кратко — нет... иначе в шифровании не было бы смысла... всегда есть способы полного перебора и других атак, но на всё это могут уйти годы...

Comment: Понятно спасибо.

Comment: да, кстати, если зашифрован только `/home`, а не весь диск и задача «не переустанавливать систему» (без сохранения пользовательских данных), то можно загрузится с live'а (или даже в root-shell через `init=/bin/bash`), то можно просто пересоздать раздел под `/home`...

Comment: Что конкретно нужно? Важны данные внутри ли нужно восстановить функционал компа?

Comment: Данные не важны. Самое главное функционал компа. Не хочу все заного переустановить.

Comment: на будущее: можно иметь несколько паролей в LUKS